# Text-selection on PDF in Preview on Mojave too dark

Tags: pdf, preview, mojave, color, dark-mode

Selected text on PDFs in Preview shows up in dark brown since upgrading to Mojave. 
When selecting text on a PDF with black text on light background, Preview uses the dark highlight that I assume is meant for white text on dark background in Dark Mode.

[image]

I am inclined to believe that it's a problem with PDFKit as the same behavior is observable in Skim, which also relies on PDFKit.

However, when viewing the same PDF in Safari, the selection shows up fine:

[image]

I'm on a 2016 MacBook Pro with macOS 10.14.2. 
Dark mode selected in System Preferences.

[image]

What I have tried and which did not resolve the issue:

- Restart
- Manually choose a lighter color in System Preferences.
- Select Light Mode in System Preferences and restart.
- Delete com.apple.preview ~/Library/Containers/ and restart.

When choosing a lighter color in the preferences, it does change the color of the selection to a more blue-ish or more green-ish brown or whatever, but it remains dark. Even when choosing white it shows up in brown.

EDIT:
I just came across a non-Apple **and non-PDF** (edit2) program where the same thing happens: BBEdit. Text on white background while in Dark Mode appears in dark brown when selected. 
It does not happen in TextEdit.

Comment: The inverse problem has also been reported: text selection not highlighted at all! --- see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/362432